# Show that Lebesgue integration is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable on the real line. For $\chi_A$ (the characteristic function of the set $A$), we know that $\int_Ef=\int_{\chi_E}$. Then, define:

$$F = \begin{cases}  \int_{[0,x]}f &\text{if }  x\ge 0 \\ 
\ - \int_{[0,x]}f &\text{if } x\lt 0 \end{cases}
$$

Show that:

1) $F$ is continuous, and

2) If $F = 0$, then $f \stackrel{a.e.}{=} 0$.

I know that I need to find sequences (fn) that converge and that their left and right limits are equal. I think I need to use the DMC, but I have no idea on how exactly to apply it and find these limits.

Answer (score 0):

2) requires Lebesgue's Theorem which says that $\frac 1 h\int_x^{x+h} f(y)\, dy \to f(x)$ as $ h \to 0$ for almost all $x$. Since $\int_x^{x+h} f(y)\, dy=F(x+h)-F(x)$ we get 2) immediately.

1) follows from the fact that $|\int_A f(x)\, dx| \to 0$ as $m(A) \to 0$. [ $m$ being Lebesgue measure]. This statement can be verified easily when $f$ is  a simple function. For the general case use the fact that given $\epsilon >0$ there is a simple integrable function $g$ such that $|\int f-\int g |<\epsilon$.